# How to update a page that is not built from articles?

Tags: content

So, I'm trying to update a page on a site I am maintaining and it doesn't seem to be made up from articles. I have explored the menu for the page, and there doesn't seem to be any obvious candidates for what it on the page (either modules or articles). I've found the Google Maps plug in for the page, but I'm lost. I think the page is hard coded somewhere, but I'm not sure where that would be. Any ideas?

After turning off the search engine friendly URLS I got this:
`index.php?option=com_contact&view=contact&id=1&Itemid=102`

Comment: turn off sef url and it maybe give you some more clues about the page

Comment: How can I do that?

Comment: Go to System->global configuration -> SEO setting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, this was apparently an honest to goodness contact page.